# What is the name of this tiny spider?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, arachnology

Found this spider on the flower bud in my garden. It measures about 5mm. I am from Kuching, Sarawak, Malaysia.

[image]

Comment: it's a jumping spider, there's some south east asian jumping spiders here: https://image.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/3499364/481322845/stock-photo-jumping-spider-in-southeast-asia-481322845.jpg

Answer (score -1):

It looks like some kind of jumping spider, possibly an iridescent jumping spider based on your location (Family: Salticidae, Genus: Cosmophasis). Here is some information on it! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmophasis

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. You are more likely to get a positive response to your answer if you explain why your identification is correct. Specifically, please [edit] your answer to add discussion of key features that led you to this conclusion and supporting references or at least validated images. Without this your answer is indistinguishable from opinion. ——— Please also take the [tour] and then consult the [help] pages for additional advice on [Answer] and [Ask] effectively on this site.